# Vue Router: access page directly from browser address bar

Tags: nginx, vue.js, vue-router, html5-history

I'm using Vue Router history mode for my Vue.js app. My problem is that, when I try to refresh a page that is not the root page, or enter its URL in the browser address bar, "page not found" 404 is displayed.

Now, in the Vue Router guide they warn about this (see https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations), and suggest the solution to "add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives in".

With this solution, if I try to access one of my non-root pages (with corresponding URL) through the browser address bar, the root page will be displayed. Is this interpretation correct?

My question: is there a way to achieve the behaviour such that I can access my different pages **directly** from the browser address bar, and upon refresh stay on the same page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the aforementioned configuration. Your backend will route all requests to index.html. Then when the Vue-Router is mounted, it will check the URL and provide the corresponding component. The implementation above will work.